# React element incorrectly changes position when adding text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, laravel, position

I am creating a simple react component in a laravel project to show product thumbnails from my database. While testing my elements i noticed that when i add any sort of text the divs change position incorrectly.

[image]

As can be seen above, whenever i add text to one of my `product-card` it will slide down the page, while the empty divs will stay above. [ I am also using Bootstrap 4 and Laravel if that makes a difference]

My **React component** code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export default class Featured extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container featured-container">
                <div className="product-card">{this.props.testdata}</div>
                <div className="product-card"></div>
                <div className="product-card">test</div>
                <div className="product-card"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

var data = $('#featured').data("testdata");

if (document.getElementById('featured')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Featured testdata={ data } />, document.getElementById('featured'));
}
```

Some applied **CSS**:

```
.product-card{
        background-color: rgb(221, 210, 179);
        display: inline-block;
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

I new to react frontend, can anyone explain to me why this is standard behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `container` following styling:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Working Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vqbqud?file=src/style.css)